# mysql db insert error when using blob value

Tags: python, mysql, blob

using python adbapi the insert a row in a table in mysql

like insert ,id is a int, value is a blob

```
db.runQuery("INSERT INTO t (id, blob_value) VALUES (%(id)s, %(blob_value)s)", \
{
    "id" : id,
    "blob_value" : blob_value
}
```

`Traceback: <class '_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError'>: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near INSERT INTO t (id, blob_value) VALUES (%(id)s, %(blob_value)s)",`

and I think it could be a quote character - ' in the `blob_value`, is these the matter why it failed?

OK, the reason is the table name - "unlock" which is a key word of mysql.

Would any one help how to do delete a table named "unlock"?

Comment: What happens when you run the same code with a blob_value not containing any quotes?

Comment: thanks, i test it with an string without quote, the error still exists.

Comment: Do you have the necessary quotation marks around the blob? Is the blob really text only? Otherwise you will have to deal with it in a different kind i think

Comment: I know the problem, i named the table "unlock" which is a key word of mysql. so a create a table named "unlock" i can't use it anymore. 
the question is how to delete the table "unlock" after all.

Answer (score 1):

Short answers:

```
DROP TABLE `UNLOCK`
SELECT * FROM `UNLOCK`
```

Use the mighty `

Answer (score 1):

Just put backticks around the table name:

```
drop table `unlock`;
```